# I don't understand why it should be 1/2 when it is non negative

Tags: logarithms

> Question:$log_{4}(log_{2}(log_{5}(625)))$

I started solving from inside of the question.

I got $4$ then I took it as exponent for log base $2$. I got $2$ then following the same method I got $2$ as the final solution but in the textbook, they have given it as $1/2$. I don't get why it should be in reciprocal when it wasn't negative.

Comment: $\log_4(\log_2(\log_5(625)))=\log_4(\log_2(4))=\log_4(2)=\frac{1}{2}.$

Answer (score 2):

From the inside...
$$
\log_4\Big(\log_2\big(\log_5(625)\big)\Big)
=
\log_4\Big(\log_2\big(4\big)\Big)
=
\log_4\Big(2\Big)
=\frac{1}{2}
$$
The last one is because $2^2=4$ and $2 = 4^{1/2}$.